# drupal site giving error after being hosted for more then 3 months

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

My drupal site is giving me this errors now after being hosted for 3 months... here is the error..

```
    Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/index.php:1) in /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 1162

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/index.php:1) in /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 726

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/index.php:1) in /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 727

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/index.php:1) in /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 728

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/index.php:1) in /home/hotsign1/public_html/posephotography.co.uk/includes/bootstrap.inc on line 729
```

I have not done anything with the site... what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your site appears to have been hacked and includes malware on it. Google Chrome reports that your site is including references to another site known to host malware. I'd suspect your hacker made some errors when including his code into your site.

Either way, looks like time to recover your backups and do some security updates or forensics before you take it live again.

Comment: Yes, definatly, there's rogue javascript being served. I'm looking at it to try to decipher it.

Comment: It's embedding an iframe to http://tdsNNNNN.4mydomain.com/stds/go.php?sid=1. (NNNNN replacing a real number).

Comment: how to check this in browser?

Comment: Look at the DOM Explorer in Chrome or Firefox. Really wouldn't recommend doing that on a Windows machine, though. In fact, I'd work on making sure your personal computer is secure before doing anything else, as it's highly likely that iframe is serving up some sort of nasties.

Comment: If you have a linux box handy, you could wget http://posephotography.co.uk and then look at the page in a text editor. If you have ssh access to the server, you could download a fresh version of drupal and diff the directories to see what in core was changed. These options would help limit your exposure to the "nasties" as @tyler-eaves calls them. :-)

There are some of the larger hosts that have seen this sort of activity pretty regularly recently. One had a potential exposure of several usernames and passwords. Others just seem to be routinely cracked into. Drupal may not be the problem.